# can anyone explain this error when using ntplib in pythonanywhere?

Tags: pythonanywhere

I'm using NTPlib in my program which runs fine on my machine but when i schedule it to run from pythonanyhere , I'm getting the following error, `File "/home/somasundharam/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ntplib.py", line 306, in request
    s.sendto(query_packet.to_data(), sockaddr)
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

what should i do to avoid this?

The below is the code:

I have ignored adding mailing part of the code as it was copied from internet, i'm running this pgm in python 2.7 because `firebase` library used in the code has a term `async` used as a var name which happens to be a keyword in python 3.7, on my machine i changed it to smthg else like `asyncx` and it worked fine, but i don't know how to change the same in `pythonanywhere`

I installed all the packages using `pip2.7` command to run it on python 2.7 as mentioned earlier.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# coding: utf-8 
from firebase import firebase
import ntplib
from time import ctime
import pandas as pd
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://@#$%^&.firebaseio.com/" , None)
c = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = c.request('asia.pool.ntp.org', version=3)
date_str = ctime(response.tx_time).split()
filename = date_str[0]+'_'+date_str[1]+'_'+date_str[2]+'_'+date_str[4]+".csv"
recipients = firebase.get("mailing list" , '')
mail_ids = list(recipients.values())
time_stamp = firebase.get("Time stamp" , '')
temp = firebase.get("TEMP SENSOR",'')
gas = firebase.get("GAS SENSOR", '')
humidity = firebase.get("HUMIDITY SENSOR",'')
sendata = [list(time_stamp.values()) ,list(temp.values()) , list(gas.values()) , list(humidity.values())]
sensor = pd.DataFrame(sendata)
sensor = sensor.transpose()
sensor.columns= ["Time Stamp","Temperature(deg C)" , "Gas Sensor(V)" , "Humidity(%)"]
sensor.to_csv(filename , index = False)
```

thanks,

Comment: Could you show the code and tell how do you run it?

Comment: also probably equally important- what's the full error stacktrace?

Comment: @conrad Here's the error: (sorry for late reply)                                                
 ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/somasundharam/firebase_iot_integration.py", line 14, in <module>
    response = c.request('asia.pool.ntp.org', version=3)
  File "/home/somasundharam/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ntplib.py", line 306, in request
    s.sendto(query_packet.to_data(), sockaddr)
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted```

Answer (score 0):

This is because free PythonAnywhere users are restricted to a whitelist of HTTP/HTTPS sites: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/

Comment: i'm using that library only for generating a file name with current day's date and day, is there any other way of doing it, also any particular reason that this website is not white listed..? any help is appreciated , @conrad

Comment: It looks like the library you're using is trying to make a direct NTP to the site in question, so it could not be whitelisted as it's not using HTTP or HTTPS.  If all you need is a human-readable timestamp, could you not just use Python's strftime method, like this: `datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")`...?